# How to use a method of a component in service in angular 5?

Tags: angular

In my project I want to use a method of a component in service. I want to call ngOnInit() of AdvisorComponent in AdminService. The service is like this:

```
import {AdminAdvisorListComponent} from "../components/admin- 
components/admin-advosor-list/admin-advisor-list.component";

@Injectable()
export class AdminService {

public token: string;
public headers: any;

constructor(private http: Http,
          private apiService: ApiService,
          private adminAdvisorList: AdminAdvisorListComponent) {}

initializeAdvisorPage() {
this.adminAdvisorList.ngOnInit();
 }
}
```

and the AdminAdvisorListComponent code is:

```
import {AdminService} from '../../../services/admin.service';

export class AdminAdvisorListComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private adminService: AdminService){}
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.adminService.getAdvisorList().subscribe(
        res => {
            if (res) {
                this.users = res;
            }
        });
}
```

with these codes it errors

> Can't resolve all parameters for AdminAdvisorListComponent: (?, [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]).
>   what should I do for this request?
>   Thanks for helping in advanced.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. Components use services, not vice-versa. And ngOnInit() is called by the framework: you should never call that method yourself.

Comment: Rethink your design. It is not a good idea to call a UI component from a service. In particular, you don't want to call a life cycle method manually.

Comment: Components are not injectable. They are not registered with Angular's injectors. So this is not possible. Services should not be initializing components. Consider using the router instead.

Comment: u cant inject a component . also u are trying to do a circular dependency injection that isnt possible either

Comment: It will also cause circular dependency issues if you are injecting service into the component as well.

Comment: but I want if in another component a user submitted the list of Advisor that gets in ngOninit method, gets update. so I decided to call ngOnInit method when user submitted.

Comment: Here is the documentation on how to communicate between components. Read it. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction